# How to declare outside of module

Tags: vba, variables, module, between

In my worksheet I have two modules, one is full of subs and the other I would like to use for global declarations.

For example, in module 2 I would like:

```
Sub Declarations()

Public Setup As Worksheet
Public Squad As Worksheet
Public Bio As Worksheet

Set Setup = Sheets("Setup")
Set Squad = Sheets("Squad")
Set Bio = Sheets("Bio")

End Sub
```

And then in each sub just begin with:

```
call Declarations
```

But this doesn't work. I've read about 20 threads on the matter and just struggle to understand. Looking at other people's code, it's completely different to what I'm trying to achieve which I feel is quite simple, and I can't relate it to my own work.
Phrases like "passing from subs or functions as parameters" - what does this mean exactly?

In my simple mind, it's as easy as
1. Go to Declarations
2. Read that stuff
3. Come back to my sub with that information

Even if I have multiple subs in the same module, I can't figure out how to keep integers stored across different subs. I have, for example:

```
'2. Prepare Vectors
'--------------------------------------------------
Set Clubs = Sheets("Database").Range("DR:DR")

For Each C In Clubs

    If IsEmpty(C) Then Exit For

    If C = Squad.Range("A1") Then

        Select Case C.Offset(0, -112).Value

            Case Is = "G"

                Gc = Gc + 1
                ReDim Preserve Goalkeepers(Gc)
                Goalkeepers(Gc) = C.Offset(0, -121)

            Case Is = "D"

                Dc = Dc + 1
                ReDim Preserve Defenders(Dc)
                Defenders(Dc) = C.Offset(0, -121)

            Case Is = "M"

                Mc = Mc + 1
                ReDim Preserve Midfielders(Mc)
                Midfielders(Mc) = C.Offset(0, -121)

            Case Is = "A"

                Ac = Ac + 1
                ReDim Preserve Attackers(Ac)
                Attackers(Ac) = C.Offset(0, -121)

        End Select

    End If

Next C
'--------------------------------------------------
```

in which I give values to the constants Gc, Dc, Mc, Ac. I've tried using these constants a little further down in the module in a different sub and it just sees them as "empty". I understand this, as the values are not stored, but setting them to

```
Public Gc as Integer
```

doesn't work either.

Sorry to ramble. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public variables need to be defined outside of your Sub, in the module itself.

```
Public Setup As Worksheet
Public Squad As Worksheet
Public Bio As Worksheet

Sub Declarations()
  Set Setup = Sheets("Setup")
  Set Squad = Sheets("Squad")
  Set Bio = Sheets("Bio")
End Sub
```

Note that public variables will preserve their value between subsequent calls to your Subs. In this concrete example it might be enough to call Declarations() once at the start.